# Find the mode across several columns in mysql table for a specific row

Tags: mysql

I know how to find the mode (most common value) within a single column in mysql, but I'm trying to figure out if I can find the mode across several columns for a specific row. So far I'm coming up empty handed with how to do it.

My table looks like this:

```
dataid    Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr
a          0      1      1      1
b          0      0      0      1
c          1      0      0      0
d          7      0      3      3
```

The modes for each row would be:

```
a 1
b 0
c 0
d 3
```

Average doesn't work for the results I need in the data I'm using so I need to find the most common value for each row across all the columns. I know this doesn't exist, but what I'm looking for is something along the lines of

```
"select mode(Jan+Feb+Mar+Apr) from tablename where dataid=c"
```

(my ultimate goal is to find all the dataids in the table where the mode is zero for the monthly columns)

Is there some easy way to do this (without expensive subqueries) or am I better off calculating the mode in php and adding that to the table as a separate column? This table gets updated so the mode value in the table would have to be updated each time, and I only need it for one quick project so was trying to avoid that route.

Comment: Normalize your table. [Click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Changing the structure of the table isn't an option unfortunately.

Comment: Make sure that you notify whoever designed it that they designed it poorly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this what you ultimately want?

```sql
SELECT dataid
FROM your_table
WHERE
    IF(Jan, 1, 0) +
    IF(Feb, 1, 0) +
    IF(Mar, 1, 0) +
    IF(Apr, 1, 0) < 3
```